# Playing a Sound for a pre specified time using timer in .Net Forms C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a problem in .Net Windows Forms. Where I need to click an image and play a sound for a certain duration defined by a variable ("im.duration"). I have a timer as well with the tick Eventhandler attached. By the following code below the sound plays repeatedly without stopping.

How is it possible to make any adjustments to make the sound play for a specified duration?

```
private void Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Image im in panel2.Controls.OfType<Image>())
            {
                if (sender == im)
                { 
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                    count = 0;
                    timer1.Start();
                    string fileToPlay = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\ImageSound\" + im.sound.ToString() + ".wav";
                    SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(fileToPlay);
                    while (count <= im.Duration)
                    {
                        sp.Play();
                    }
                    timer1.Enabled = false;
                    sp.Stop();
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
        }
```

Comment: This question doesn't relate to the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: You must get rid of the while-loop, no events can fire while the main thread is stuck in that loop.  So count never increases and the loop keeps looping forever.  You already have that timer, might as well also use it to stop the sound.  Make sp a variable of the form class.

Comment: @HansPassant By doing this, the sound is played in full.


SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(fileToPlay);
                    sp.Play();
                    if (count >= im.noteDuration)
                    {
                        timer1.Enabled = false;
                        sp.Stop();
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Duration` is the number of milliseconds to play the sound file, you could do:

```
private async void Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image im = (Image)sender;
    string fileToPlay = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ImageSound", im.sound.ToString() + ".wav");
    SoundPlayer sp = new SoundPlayer(fileToPlay);
    sp.Play();
    await Task.Delay(im.Duration);
    sp.Stop();
}
```

If `Duration` is the number seconds, then change `im.Duration` to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(im.Duration)`.

In my testing, this successfully cut off an 8 second .wav file at whatever shorter duration I specified.

Note that we don't need the `for` loop at all.  We simply cast `sender` to class `Image`.

By the way, `Image` is a horrible name for your class since that is already a built-in class in .Net: [Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)